# How to find and populate the ID wise, last closed date from the "open_close" status column into new column "last_closed_datetime"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the sample dataset & expected result output.

Sample dataset:-

```
ID  Status      Date     Amount Open_Close
1   New         01/05/20    20     Open
1   Removed     02/05/20    30    Close
1   New         02/05/20    50     Open
1   In-Progress 03/05/20    20     Open
1   Fixed       04/05/20    50    Close
2   New         05/05/20    30     Open
2   Removed     05/05/20    20    Close
3   New         05/05/20    30     Open
3   Assigned    05/05/20    50     Open
3   In-Progress 05/05/20    20     Open
3   Fixed       09/05/20    50    Close
4   New         12/05/20    20     Open
4   Assigned    13/05/20    30     Open
4   Fixed       13/05/20    20    Close
```

Expected Results:-

```
ID  Status      Date     Amount Open_Close  Last Close Date
1   New         01/05/20    20     Open       04/05/20
1   Removed     02/05/20    30    Close       04/05/20
1   New         02/05/20    50     Open       04/05/20
1   In-Progress 03/05/20    20     Open       04/05/20
1   Fixed       04/05/20    50    Close       04/05/20
2   New         05/05/20    30     Open       05/05/20
2   Removed     05/05/20    20    Close       05/05/20
3   New         05/05/20    30     Open       09/05/20
3   Assigned    05/05/20    50     Open       09/05/20
3   In-Progress 05/05/20    20     Open       09/05/20
3   Fixed       09/05/20    50    Close       09/05/20
4   New         12/05/20    20     Open       13/05/20
4   Assigned    13/05/20    30     Open       13/05/20
4   Fixed       13/05/20    20    Close       13/05/20
```

In order to identify the last close date, then need to get the count for whenever status has changed from open to close, it counts 1, if there are continuous open, need to ignore that count.

Eg:-
Expected Results:-

```
ID  Status      Date     Amount Open_Close  Flip_count
1   New         01/05/20    20     Open        3
1   Removed     02/05/20    30    Close        3
1   New         02/05/20    50     Open        3
1   In-Progress 03/05/20    20     Open        3
1   Fixed       04/05/20    50    Close        3
2   New         05/05/20    30     Open        2
2   Removed     05/05/20    20    Close        2
3   New         05/05/20    30     Open        2
3   Assigned    05/05/20    50     Open        2
3   In-Progress 05/05/20    20     Open        2
3   Fixed       09/05/20    50    Close        2
4   New         12/05/20    20     Open        2
4   Assigned    13/05/20    30     Open        2
4   Fixed       13/05/20    20    Close        2
```

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.  You seem to have two desired result sets -- which makes the question a bit broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*, 
       max(case when open_close = 'Close' then date end) over (partition by id) as lastclosedate
from table t;
```